# Javascript "Not equal to" feature from a prompt

Tags: javascript, variables, prompt, case-sensitive

I am a very very beginner in Javascript and am trying to use only very basics. I am trying to only allow two certain words to be accepted into a variable prompt. If anything else other than the two allowed words are entered, I want to display a message saying only the two words are allowed, and to try again until it's correct. This is the code I am working with so far. Everything is working well until the last section

```
console.log("Start of the program");

var letters = /^[a-zA-Z]*$/;

var number= prompt ("Which number between 1 and 30 do you want to translate?");
    
    while (number <1) {
        alert("Please type an integer number between 1 and 30");
        var number= prompt ("Which number between 1 and 30 do you want to translate?");
}
    while (number >30) { 
        alert("Please type an integer number between 1 and 30");
        var number= prompt ("Which number between 1 and 30 do you want to translate?");
}

    while (letters.test(number)) {
        alert("Please use digits");
        var number= prompt ("Which number between 1 and 30 do you want to translate?");
}

if (number => 1 && number <= 30) {
    var lang= prompt ("Which language do you want to translate into, French or German?");
}
while(lang != "French" != "German") {
    alert("Only French or German is allowed");
    var lang= prompt ("Which language do you want to translate into, French or German?");
}
```

Even if I enter "French" or "German" I still receive the "Only French or German is allowed" alert continuously. If I change the "while (lang !=)" to an "if (lang !=)" I receive the alert once regardless of if French or German has been correctly used, and then the program continues. I also would like it to not be case sensitive (accept French, french, FRENCH etc.) in my result which uses this code currently

```
if (number == 1 && lang == "French") {
        alert("The translation is " +frenchNumbers[1]);
```

Any help would be much appreciated

Thanks, Brad

Comment: @Kinglish, this needs `&&`, not `||`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're missing `&& lang` here:

`while(lang != "French" && lang != "German")`

JavaScript (nor any other language I'm currently aware of) allows you to compare a variable to two different values like this, without using a boolean operator and then repeating the name of the variable.

Interestingly enough, `lang != "French" != "German"` is valid syntax, but it doesn't mean what you might think.

First `lang != "French"` is evaluated to either `true` or `false`. Then what happens next is either:

`true != "German"` or `false != "German"`

...and both of those are always true.

Comment: Perfect! Thank you so much for the fast reply, works perfectly. I'm sure there is probably an easier way to do it but I have gone and updated that section so it is now:

while(lang != "French" && lang != "french" && lang != "FRENCH" && lang != "German" && lang != "german" && lang != "GERMAN" ) {
 alert("Only French or German is allowed");
 var lang= prompt ("Which language do you want to translate into, French or German?");
}
Do you have any suggestions what I need to do so the results section will allow "French" or "french" or "FRENCH" for example?

Thanks, Brad

Comment: If you want to get fancy and use regular expressions, you can do `!/^(french|german)$/i.test(lang)`, which also easily extends to a longer list of languages. The 'i' indicates that the comparison is case-insensitive.

Comment: Another thing often done for case-insensitive tests is to do something like `lang = lang.toLowerCase()` or `lang = lang.toUpperCase()` before doing any comparisons.